# Android: adding ad at bottom and shrinking the other view

Tags: android, view, adview

I'm pretty new to Android layouts, and i'm trying to add an AdView at the bottom of my main view, and move the main view up, shrinking its height. I took a code somewhere that makes the ad appear at bottom, however the application's height does not shrink: the Ad takes the bottom of the application. I must make it programatically, with no xmls.

This is the code i have:

```
  View mainView; // of type SurfaceView
  adView = new AdView(this);
  adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
  adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
  mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
  mainLayout.addView(mainView);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
  mainLayout.addView(adView, adParams);
  setContentView(mainLayout);
```

Sometime later i show the adView:

```
  adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to android as well, but it sounds like you need to add a layout align tag to the adView. That ought to push the application up and put the add at the bottom. I hope this helps a little bit!

Answer (score 0):

its a simple one:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add your ad here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And how can i do that programatically, with no xml?

Comment: what do you exactly trying to achive?

Comment: layout is made for userinterface so if u do must of it with code, at least you have to show it in the layout.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_user_interface_layouts.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_acitivities.htm

Comment: I'm still unable to use your code because you used XML and i cannot use XML. I tried to convert the XML to Java code as in my sample, but i didnt succeed.

Comment: there is no way to do it all by code in android, using xml in android is easy, go download Aide app install it follow android tutorial then you will know what to do. you need to add id to your code and use your code id in xml file, the xml code that gave you is just for showing how to put adview in the bottom not for converting into code.